# En event handler wired to LinkButton.Click is being called when the page loads

Tags: asp.net, event-handling

This is the code I'm using. The way I understood it, **LinkButton1_Click** is supposed to be called only when I click **LinkButton1**. Unfortunatelly, the method is being called when the page loads, so I'm kimd of lost. Is there anything wrong somewhere in the code?

```
protected void LinkButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        //Do something
}

override protected void OnInit(EventArgs e)
{
        InitializeComponent();
        base.OnInit(e);
}
private void InitializeComponent()
{
        this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.Page_Load);
        this.LinkButton1.Click += new EventHandler(this.LinkButton1_Click);          
 }
```

Thanks for helping

Comment: Does the `LinkButton1_Click` method executed on initial request or page rendered, returned to client and after that LinkButton1's Click event fired?

Comment: Is AutoEventWireup property set to true in your @Page directive? Since you're wiring up event handlers manually, make sure it is set to false. Not sure about the button click handler, but Page_Load will be firing twice otherwise.

Comment: I just tried the exact same stuff, but it worked fine for me! Although once you click on the link button and then you refresh the page then ofcourse the postback happens again and the link button event handler gets called again. but this can be fixed by doing IsPostBack check in OnInit(). AutoEventWireUp was true so that didn't hamper anything either.

Comment: it is working for me, can you send the project? I think there must be some more code written by you that might causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not calling "LinkButton1_Click" from code or using some javascript to finally trigger this method, then this should not be happening. 
However I had similar problems that were caused by Visual Studio debug output.
Go to Visual Studio main menu and choose "Build" -> "Clean Solution".
You can also remove your "LinkButton1" from designer and force to rebuild solution. This should force debug files to be rebuild and phantom call will dissapear.